# Further understanding of unsigned integer overflow in C++14

Tags: c++, c++14, integer-overflow, unsigned-integer

Why does the [following code](http://cpp.sh/8c72o) fail for the case of `uint8_t`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <stack>

template <typename TT>
void PrintNumberScientificNotation (TT number) {
  constexpr TT             kBase{10};          // Base of the numerical system.
            TT             xx{number};         // Number to convert.
            TT             exponent{};         // Exponent.
            std::stack<TT> fractional_part{};  // Values in the fractional part.

  do {
    fractional_part.push(xx%kBase);
    xx /= kBase;
    exponent++;
  } while (xx > kBase);

  std::cout << xx << '.';
  while (!fractional_part.empty()) {
    std::cout << fractional_part.top();
    fractional_part.pop();
  }
  std::cout << " x 10^" << exponent << std::endl;
}

int main () {
  uint8_t number_1{255};
  PrintNumberScientificNotation(number_1);  // Does not work.
  uint16_t number_2{255};
  PrintNumberScientificNotation(number_2);  // Works.
  uint16_t number_3{65'535};
  PrintNumberScientificNotation(number_3);  // Works.
  uint32_t number_4{4'294'967'295};
  PrintNumberScientificNotation(number_4);  // Works.
  uint64_t number_5{18'446'744'073'709'551'615};
  PrintNumberScientificNotation(number_5);  // Works.
}
```

Execute: http://cpp.sh/8c72o

Output:

```
. x 10^
2.55 x 10^2
6.5535 x 10^4
4.294967295 x 10^9
1.8446744073709551615 x 10^19
```

It is my understanding that `uint8_t` is able to represent unsigned integer numbers up to and including 255 (`UINT8_MAX`). Why can I represent the maximum values for all of the other representations?

Comment: What do you mean by dos not work.

Comment: I have updated the question to show the output it produces, yet SO messes with it. I suggest going to the link where the code is and run it :)

Comment: Since the question has been closed, I can't post this as an answer. But instead of mangling the type when you call `PrintNumberScientificNotation`, as two answers have suggested, write a specialization: `template <> void PrintNumberScientificNotation(uint8_t val) { PrintNumberScientificNotation(static_cast<unsigned>(val); }`. That way, `PrintNumberScientificNotation(number_1)` just works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mathematical part of your code is fine, the printing is broken.

If you use `cout` for `uint_t`, it will interpret the `uint_t` as a character code. That's because `uint_t` is a type alias for unsigned char.

A possible fix is to explicitly convert to integer:

```
  std::cout << unsigned(xx) << '.';
  while (!fractional_part.empty()) {
    std::cout << unsigned(fractional_part.top());
    fractional_part.pop();
  }
  std::cout << " x 10^" << unsigned(exponent) << std::endl;
```

Comment: It's not necessarily an ASCII code; just a character code. ASCII is by far the most common character encoding, but it's not the only one. That aside, good answer. +1.

Comment: Oh, true. Fixed it :)

Answer (score 3):

uint8_t is treated like a char thus it will print the character with the ASCII code.  You have to convert the uint8_t value to unsigned before printing it as follow:

```
uint8_t number_1{255};
PrintNumberScientificNotation(unsigned(number_1));
```